# How to detach firestore listener

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to FireStore. I created a ListenerRegistration to update my Recycler View. I know my implementation may not be perfect, but every time my activity got destroyed, my app throws an error on the lines that are inside this Listener. I don't know why, but mt registration.remove() is not working before on destroy or after finish() activity. Can someone help?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private ListenerRegistration registration;
  private com.google.firebase.firestore.Query query;

  private void requestPacienteList(){

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    query = db.collection("Hospital");
    registration = query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : documentSnapshots){

                if(documentSnapshot.get("nome").equals("Santa Clara")){

                    hospital = documentSnapshot.toObject(Hospital.class);
                    hospital.setHospitalDocumentKey(documentSnapshot.getId());
                    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

                    db.collection("Hospital")
                            .document(hospital.getHospitalDocumentKey())
                            .collection("Pacientes")
                            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

                                 @Override
                                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                                    homeModelList.clear();
                                    for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : documentSnapshots){

                                        final Paciente paciente = documentSnapshot.toObject(Paciente.class);
                                        paciente.setPacienteKey(documentSnapshot.getId());
                                        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                                        db.collection("Pessoa")
                                                .document(paciente.getProfissionalResponsavel())
                                                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                                                        Profissional profissional = documentSnapshot.toObject(Profissional.class);
                                                        int[] covers = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_person_black};
                                                        HomeModel p = new HomeModel(paciente.getNome()+" "+paciente.getSobrenome(),paciente.getBox(),paciente.getLeito(),
                                                        covers[0],profissional.getNome()+ " "+profissional.getSobrenome(),paciente.getPacienteKey());
                                                        homeModelList.add(p);
                                                        homeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                        prepareListaPacientes();
                                                    }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    }
            }
        }
    });

    switch (id){

        case R.id.logout:

            if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()!=null)
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

            Intent it = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(it);

            if(registration!=null)
                registration.remove();

            finish();

            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
    }
  }

}
```

> My onDestroy method:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    registration.remove();
}
```

> When I remove this if:

```
if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()!=null)
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

My problem is gone. But if I don't, I get the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.Object
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(java.lang.Class)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                   at santauti.app.Activities.Home.HomeActivity$4$1$1.onEvent(HomeActivity.java:200)
>                                                                   at santauti.app.Activities.Home.HomeActivity$4$1$1.onEvent(HomeActivity.java:197)
>                                                                   at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                   at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzd.onEvent(Unknown Source)
>                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzejz.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeka.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: From what activity lifecycle method (e.g. `onDestroy`, `onStop`, `onPause`) to you call `registration.remove()`?

Comment: at onDestroy method

Comment: Please update your question with that information and the error that is thrown. You should be able to find the full stack trace in logcat.

Comment: Aparently the error occurs when I signOut the user from Firebase.Auth.getInstance().signOut(); If I remove this line, my app doesn't crash. I'll update with these information

Comment: I've found the error. Those nested DB search should be removed. Maybe there is another solution to directly search for those registers, but I don't know how right now.

Comment: For more clean coding, try to use [Tasks.call()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections) method.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you [use `addSnapshotListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) you attach a listener that gets called for any changes. Apparently you have to [detach those listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) before the activity gets destroyed. An alternative is to [add the `activity` to your call to `addSnapshotListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#addSnapshotListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot%3E)):

```
 db.collection("Pessoa").document(paciente.getProfissionalResponsavel())
   .addSnapshotListener(MainActivity.this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
```

*You'll need to update `MainActivity.this` to match your code.*

By passing in the activity, Firestore can clean up the listeners automatically when the activity is stopped.

Yet another alternative is to use [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) to get those nested documented, which just reads the document once. Since it only reads once, there is no listener to clean up.

Comment: WOW! I didnt see this argument on documentation. It worked like a charm! Thank you so much man.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Thanks you very much sir

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen - How do you "reattach" or recreate a **RegistrationListener** once removed? I have a UI component I'd like to toggle between real time data and swipe-to-refresh modes.

Comment: There is no concept of re-registering. To register again, just run the same code that you used to register it the first time around.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen **By passing in the activity, Firestore can clean up the listeners automatically when the activity is stopped.** do you mean activity onStop()? Then how can we attach and listen from it again after onResume()?

Comment: It removes the listener when activity goes to background. And doesn't work anymore even if the activity comes foreground again. It should ideally stop on activity finish or listen again activity comes to foreground.

Answer (score 13):

use `registration.remove();` for Stop listening to changes

```
Query query = db.collection("cities");
ListenerRegistration registration = query.addSnapshotListener(
        new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            // ...
        });

// ...

// Stop listening to changes
registration.remove();
```

see more about this : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener

Answer (score 3):

## ListenerRegistration is the Key

If you want to start and stop **Realtime Updates** from a FirebaseDatabase then you should register and unregister your EventListners with [ListenerRegistration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/ListenerRegistration).

> Full Code:

```
MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{

      private CollectionReference collectionRef; //<- You will get realtime updates on this
      private ListenerRegistration registration;

      public void registerListner(){
           registration = collectionRef.addSnapshotListener(this);      
      }

      public void unregisterListener(){
           registration.remove();           //<-- This is the key
      }


      @Override
      public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

          for(DocumentChange dc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){

              Log.d("Tag",  dc.getType().toString()+" "+dc.getDocument().getData());
        
          }
      }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MVVM architecture specifically the ViewModel and LiveData architecture classes, then it's not a good idea to pass an activity via addSnapshotListener() method.

What you need to do is store the ListenerRegistration from the addSnapshotListener method and manually remove the listener on onInactive() method of LiveData class.

Comment: Agree with you. Can you advise how we can Store ListenerRegistration?

Answer (score 0):

## Add these two method in your code, this will solve your problem.

```
@Override
public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, 
FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if (e != null) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, ":onEvent", e);
        return;
    }
}
```

### and

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (registration!= null) {
        registration.remove();
        registration = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `registration` here?

Comment: private ListenerRegistration registration;

Comment: @kelehv addSnapshotListener returns ListenerRegistration (like a Disposable for rx)